# How to send transactions to the sandbox paypal using paypal API?

Tags: paypal, postman, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create some payments with transactions on my sandbox API. I followed the doc here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create and inserted the request body in postman but I get a 404 error. I am not using the deprecated endpoint. Can someone help?

Comment: Duplicated question - same text repeated twice. Please, provide more details/examples of your problem instead of duplicating text.

Comment: Sorry about that @alexJS! I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

v1/payments is a deprecated API.

Use the current v2/checkout/orders API, [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create)

Impossible to advise on the reason for the 404 without seeing a log of your request and response, but make sure you are successfully obtaining an access token first. There is a postman collection at https://www.postman.com/paypal/